# Should this library file actually be in the header files instead?

Tags: c

I got this flowchart from a book on C.

[image: the flowchart]

I get the differences between headers and libraries, however in my understanding shouldn't header files be the code before compilation and not library files.I still don't understand this flowchart 100%. Is it wrong or am I the one wrong here?

EDIT: The name of the book is "Introduction to C Programming" by "Reema Thareja"

Comment: I am inclined to think that what your book means by "library files" is different, perhaps more generalized, than what you mean by it (or than what I would mean by it).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Only C files go through the pre-processor. That means C source files and C header files. So there is no more generalized meaning of files that would go through the pre-processor. It looks like a definitely mistake to me.

Comment: Your imagination fails you, @bolov.  Header files associated with a given library could be considered "library files" in an English-language sense.  They are of course not "libraries" in the sense that I would use that term.  I am not trying to defend the terrible, confusing usage, but we cannot say whether it would be consistent and correct if considered in its original context.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the scheme shows "these library files" are fed into the pre-processor. That was my comment about. Whatever definition you may think of for "library files" those definitions cannot be used here because only files containing C language can be understood by the pre-processor.

Comment: I never suggested that files containing anything other than C source code could be fed to the preprocessor, @bolov.  Rather, I observed that the term "library files" could be used in sense that is *inclusive* of headers, which of course can be fed to the preprocessor.  The context of the diagram would be helpful in determining how the term actually was meant.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, that makes sense.

Comment: NeroAngelo: you could add the name of the book into the question... :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I have added it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are right: the ones in red (the one below too) should be header files.

Answer (score 2):

What the picture could mean is that the *source files* ***or*** *headers* that you `#include` are also an essential part of libraries.

---

Also, a *header* in the C standard terminology is reserved for something that comes from the system and need not be a file; if you have a your own file that you `#include`, then that too is called a [*source file*](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.2).

Comment: Excellent point that headers are not necessarily source files.